# Тестирование в Laravel: обмен данными между тестами

Tags: laravel, юнит-тесты, php7, phpunit

Пишу тесты под Laravel 5.8. Интересует, как передавать данные из одного теста в другой.

То есть, предположим, тестирую создание некой записи. В случае успешного выполнения в response мне приходит код 201 и id созданной записи. Это первый тест. Далее мне нужно чтобы этот id был передан в следующий тест и по нему мы проверили работу метода showOne, и ещё далее по этому-же id мы проверили работу метода delete. Ну и, соответственно, для этого также нужно очерёдность тестов соблюсти. Как мне это реализовать? Передачу данных между тестами и очерёдность.

Comment: Так не делается. Это нарушает сам принцип unit testing. Ваш второй тест ничего не должен знать о первом, а первый - о втором. Всё, что вне тестируемого класса, имитируется через mock.

Comment: @KAGGDesign почему нарушает? я тестирую класс Book условно. Проверяю создание, удаление, получение. Мне нужно создать -> получить ID -> проверить получение -> проверить удаление. всё в рамках одного класса Book.

Comment: Потому что все тесты должны быть независимые. ID для следующего теста задаётся константой или dataprovider, если надо проверить разные варианты.

Comment: В общем, нет таких средств передачи информации из одного теста в другой. Ровно потому, что это вне самой концепции изолированного тестирования.